# Why i cant change the value of my input

Tags: reactjs, input

I'm doing a form to modify my value on my data base but i don't understand why i cant change the value of my input on my browser.

```
<Input type="text" value={this.props.sub.text}></Input>
```

Comment: change `value` into `defaultValue` or make a controlled component.

Comment: I answered a similar question about 10 mins ago, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46219828/text-box-coming-disabled-in-react-js-using-type-script).

Comment: Also, inputs don't take any children. So just do `/>` instead of `></Input>`.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about defaultValue sorry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Altering react form but input value not editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42639577/altering-react-form-but-input-value-not-editable)